# Netbeans Highlights errors where are no errors

Tags: c++, netbeans

I use NetBeans with the C++ Plugin (Version 8.0.2). I have one class called "Settings", which gives me a huge amount of false errors, making it impossible to debug this class using NetBeans.

All errors begin here in the `hpp` file:

```
bool SetSettingString(std::string Name, std::string defaultValue, bool override = true);
bool SetSettingFloat(std::string Name, float defaultValue, bool override = true);
bool SetSettingInt(std::string Name, int defaultValue, bool override = true);
bool SetSettingBool(std::string Name, bool defaultValue, bool override = true);
bool SetSettingDouble(std::string Name, double defaultValue, bool override = true);
```

The error starts at the first `defaultValue`, also in the `cpp` file exactly at this point, NetBeans highlights nearly all the code red, as he cant resolve any identifiers. The code is clean and compiles without even a warning.

My first guess was, that NetBeans interprets `defaultValue` somehow as a keyword, but changing it to another name wont change anything. I also found on SO the suggestion to clear the usercache, which I did (deleting the `index` directory under `~/.cache/netbeans/8.0.2/`).

Has anyone any suggestion on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) is a keyword (only if used in proper context) since C++11 - it might confuse NetBeans.

It's not normal keyword (like `for` etc.) which can't be used as identifier - due to backward compatibility (with code like yours :) ), `override` will be treated as keyword only if it appears after method declaration:

```
void fun() override;
```

This code forces compiler to check if base class has virtual method `fun`.

So your code is correct, but simple IDE parsers checking for keywords might get lost. As this is only parameter name, I'd suggest changing it.